# Best practices in protractor for big pageObject files

Tags: protractor

In my previous protractor JS project (This new one I will do it with TS) I created one class for all my elements and another one for my functions, something like this:

```
specs
|_reportPage
  |_lib
    |_pageElements.js
    |_pageFunctions.js
```

Then I was importing the files as necessary, in this way was easy to find the info since the element list was long.

So far all examples online for protractor TS projects are short pageObject files with a couple of elements and methods, but I would like to know how to correctly proceed when the page requires a lot of elements and functions/methods.

For example, lets say we have 5 specs under the same folder that test the same page and this page is full of fields and tables.

What would be the best practice here? create 1 pageobject for each spec, create one long class with all the elements and functions...?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Split them in modules. Example if the page has a search bar, create class SearchBar.. Navigation Menu... extract it as another class.. picture the page in modules. At the end import them into single class that represents the page.

Comment: Hi @Infern0, thanks for the idea, it is a good way, I created different classes and i am injecting them into a main one, now my ocd is satisfied hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Extend my answer you can add additional layer as a **service** which can execute several actions from the flow in different pages.

Code example:

```
export class E2EService {
    mainPage: MainPage = new MainPage();
    innerPage: InnerPage = new InnerPage();

    doSomethingE2E() {
        this.mainPage.headerPage.weDoSomething();
        this.mainPage.contentPage.weDoSomething()

        this.innerPage.somethingComplicated();
    }
}
export class MainPage {
    public readonly headerPage: HeaderPage;
    public readonly contentPage: ContentPage;

}

export class InnerPage {
    headerPage: InnerHeaderPage;
    contentPage: InnerContentPage;

    public somethingComplicated() {
        this.headerPage.weDoSomething();
        this.contentPage.weDoSomething();
    }
}

export class ContentPage {
    private readonly elements = {
        // elements
    };

    public weDoSomething() {
        // code
    }

    public getElements() {
        return this.elements;
    }
}

export class HeaderPage {
    private readonly elements = {
        btn1: element(by.id('')),
        div: element(by.id('')),
        h2: element(by.id(''))
    };

    public weDoSomething() {
        // code
    }

    public getElements() {
        return this.elements;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Infern0's answer, I did dependency injection to the classes:

```
class HeaderElements {
  foo = element(by.id("foo"));
  //List goes on...
}

class HomePageElements {
  foo = element(by.id("foo"));
  //List goes on...
}


export class MainCommonElementsPage {
  headerElements: HeaderElements;
  homePageElements: HomePageElements;
  constructor() {
    this.headerElements = new HeaderElements();
    this.homePageElements = new HomePageElements();
  }    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practices, even for large Page Objects is this:

Each page should only have 1 page object class. All of the tools needed to access that page should be located here. Think of your page object as an API.

Don't break the PO into different parts, especially for large pages. You'll eventually need to modify the PO to adjust for content changes. Would you rather change 1 file or 12? This also ensures that each of your e2e tests will remain functional after you update the PO.

I have one PO that handles a page with a lengthy form. The form has 12 controls and three buttons (cancel, reset, and submit). I have about 30 functions that deal with the form. I don't like having more than 1-2 methods in my test, so if it gets more complicated, I add to the PO.